# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, jsx

I was creating a to do app with React js and when I call npm start, this error appears:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
this is in file App.js in src folder:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AddItem from './addItem';
import Items from './list';
import './events';
function App() {
  return (
    <body>
    <h1>
        To Do List
      </h1>
    <div >
      
      <AddItem/>
      <Items/>
    </div>
    
    </body>
     
  );

}

export default App;
```

and this is events.js file

```
let addBtn=document.getElementById('add');
let removeBtn=document.getElementById('remove');
let listOfItems=document.getElementById('items');
let addText=document.getElementById('addText');
let removeText=document.getElementById('removeText');
addBtn.addEventListener('click',add);
function add(){
  
    if(addText.value===''){
alert("Type the item you want to add first");
    }else{
let added=document.createElement('LI');
let addedTextNode=document.createTextNode(addText.value);
added.appendChild(addedTextNode);
listOfItems.appendChild(added);
localStorage.setItem('items',added.innerHTML);
}


}
```

Comment: In React if your really really need to access the DOM directly, then use a `useRef`..   But for something like `onClick` that's certainly something you don't need to access the DOM directly with.

Comment: While the linked duplicate indicates that `document.getElementById('add')` is simply not finding the element, *specifically* for what you're doing I would recommend getting rid of this code entirely and starting over entirely.  All this use of `getElementById` or `addEventListener` or `createElement`, etc. *in a React application* is most certainly the wrong approach.  You really shouldn't be directly interacting with the DOM in React like that, outside of *rare* use cases.